# unwanted double width space before inline listings when using luatexja-fontspec

Tags: luatex, fontspec, luatexja

I am seeing an extra big space (which looks like double width space) in my document before inline listings bits:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage{luatexja-fontspec}
\setmainjfont{WenQuanYi Zen Hei}

\begin{document}

foo \lstinline!bar! baz

\end{document}
```

It does not happen without `luatexja-fontspec`. Can I work around it/fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a stray space in the file `lltjp-listings.sty`

```
194 % hook!
195 \lst@AddToHook{Init}{
196   \luatexcatcodetable\CatcodeTableLTJlistings\ltj@@listing@jpcmd
197   \lccode`\~="FFFFF\lowercase{\def~{\ltj@lst@ProcessJALetter}}%"
```

(line numbers added for convenience) that should be

```
% hook!
\lst@AddToHook{Init}{%<--------HERE!!!
  \luatexcatcodetable\CatcodeTableLTJlistings\ltj@@listing@jpcmd
  \lccode`\~="FFFFF\lowercase{\def~{\ltj@lst@ProcessJALetter}}%"
  \directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback('process_input_buffer',
```

There's not much one can do other than edit (a local copy of) the file until the bug has been fixed by the `luatexja` package maintainers.

If I add the missing `%`, the output I get is

[image]

#### How did I discover it?

Not with magic. `;-)`

First I looked at the packages loaded when `luatexja-fontspec` is requested and `lltjp-listings.sty` seemed the best candidate for the spurious space.

So I added `\tracingcommands=1` before the line

```
foo \lstinline!bar! baz
```

and `\tracingcommands=0` after it to limit the search range, and compiled the file first without `luatexja-fontspec` and then with it.

With `\tracingcommands=1`, (Lua)TeX writes some diagnostic information in the `.log` file, in particular it writes

```
{blank space  }
```

whenever it executes the primitive command “issue a blank space” which may or may not have effects, depending on the current mode.

There were four such commands executed without `luatexja-fontspec` and five with it. Four of them corresponded to the ones in the other log file, the additional one was very probably the culprit. It appeared just before the execution of

```
{\catcodetable }
```

so I looked for `\luatexcatcodetable` (which is the name corresponding to the primitive `\catcodetable` when LuaLaTeX is used) and lo! The unprotected end-of-line was there! A bit of luck always helps.

So I made a copy of the file `lltjp-listings.sty` in the working directory and added the missing `%`. A run of LuaLaTeX and the output was correct. Hurray!

Comment: Wow! Did you report the bug already or should I do it myself?

Comment: @VáclavZeman Do it yourself, please.

Comment: Reported: https://sourceforge.jp/ticket/browse.php?group_id=5593&tid=34786